# Memory increase with fortran & MKL in parallel

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I wrote a program for matrix product state in Fortran 90. In this program, I use the Intel MKL library. When the compiler option is:

```
OPTIMIZE= -parallel -par-threshold90 -ipo -O3 -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -xHost

LinkLine = $(OPTIMIZE) $(DIAGNOSE) -mkl -static-intel,
```

in the runtime, the memory keeps increasing.
If I change the compiler option to:

```
OPTIMIZE= -ipo -O3 -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -xHost

LinkLine = $(OPTIMIZE) $(DIAGNOSE) -mkl=sequential -static-intel,
```

there is no problem, everything is fine.
Why does this happen? Is there any solution to this?

Follow the suggestions by Alexander, I post one of the subroutines (performing singular value decomposition for a matrix) in the following:

```
SUBROUTINE SVD(Theta,S1,S2,lambda,Din,Dout)
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: Din, Dout
COMPLEX(kind=rKind),DIMENSION(Din,Din), INTENT(IN) :: Theta

REAL(kind=rKind), INTENT(OUT) :: lambda(Dout)
COMPLEX(kind=rKind), INTENT(OUT) :: S1(Din,Dout),S2(Din,Dout)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: M(Din,Din)
REAL(kind=rKind) :: temp_lam(Din)
COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: temp_U(Din,Din), temp_V(Din,Din)
COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: WORK(10*Din)
REAL(kind=rKind) :: RWORK(5*Din)
REAL(kind=rKind), PARAMETER :: Truncation = 1E-13_rKind
INTEGER :: INFO, i

!----------------------------

M = Theta

CALL ZGESVD('A','A',Din,Din,M,Din,temp_lam,temp_U,Din,temp_V,Din,WORK,10*Din,RWORK,INFO)
lambda = 0.0_rKind
S1 = 0.0_rKind
S2 = 0.0_rKind

DO i = 1,Dout
    IF (temp_lam(i)/temp_lam(1)>Truncation) THEN
        lambda(i) = temp_lam(i)
        S1(:,i) = temp_U(:,i)
        S2(:,i) = temp_V(i,:)
    END IF
END DO

END SUBROUTINE SVD
```

And another subroutine is

```
SUBROUTINE TwoSiteUpdate(A_update,B_update,lambda_2_update,&
& A,B,lambda_1,lambda_2,U,D1,D2_old,D2_new)

! Designed for 1D MPS.

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: D1, D2_old, D2_new

COMPLEX(kind=rKind), INTENT(IN) :: A(D1,D2_old,localSize), B(D2_old,D1,localSize)

REAL(kind=rKind), INTENT(IN) :: lambda_1(D1), lambda_2(D2_old)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind), INTENT(IN) :: U(localSize,localSize,localSize,localSize)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind), INTENT(OUT) :: A_update(D1,D2_new,localSize), B_update(D2_new,D1,localSize)

REAL(kind=rKind), INTENT(OUT) :: lambda_2_update(D2_new)


COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: temp_A(D1,D2_old,localSize)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: temp_B(D2_old,D1,localSize)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: Theta(D1,localSize,D1,localSize)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: Theta_S(D1*localSize,D1*localSize)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: S1(D1*localSize,D2_new), S2(D1*localSize,D2_new)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: S1_tmp(D1,localSize,D2_new)

COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: S2_tmp(D1,localSize,D2_new)


REAL(kind=rKind), PARAMETER :: Truncation=1E-16_rKind
COMPLEX(kind=rKind) :: tmp_ele
INTEGER :: i1,i2,i3,im
INTEGER :: mA1,mB1,mA2,mB2
INTEGER :: i



!------------------- add lambda on A, B ----------------------

temp_A = 0.0_rKind
temp_B = 0.0_rKind

DO im = 1,localSize
    DO i2 = 1,D2_old
        DO i1 = 1,D1

            IF(lambda_1(i1)>Truncation) THEN
                temp_A(i1,i2,im) = A(i1,i2,im)*SQRT(lambda_1(i1))
                temp_B(i2,i1,im) = B(i2,i1,im)*SQRT(lambda_1(i1))
            END IF

        END DO
    END DO
END DO

!--------------- svd on Theta ----------------

Theta = 0.0_rKind

DO mB2 = 1,localSize
    DO i2 = 1,D1
        DO mA2 = 1,localSize
            DO i1 = 1,D1

                tmp_ele = 0.0_rKind
                DO mB1 = 1,localSize
                    DO mA1 = 1,localSize
                        DO i3 = 1,D2_old
                            tmp_ele = tmp_ele + U(mA2,mB2,mA1,mB1)*temp_A(i1,i3,mA1)*temp_B(i3,i2,mB1)
                        END DO
                    END DO
                END DO
                Theta(i1,mA2,i2,mB2) = tmp_ele

            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
END DO


Theta_S = RESHAPE(Theta,SHAPE=(/D1*localSize,D1*localSize/))

CALL SVD(Theta_S,S1,S2,lambda_2_update,D1*localSize,D2_new)

lambda_2_update = lambda_2_update/lambda_2_update(1)

S1_tmp = RESHAPE(S1,SHAPE=(/D1,localSize,D2_new/))

S2_tmp = RESHAPE(S2,SHAPE=(/D1,localSize,D2_new/))

!---------------- update A, B ----------------

A_update = 0.0_rKind
B_update = 0.0_rKind

DO im = 1,localSize
    DO i2 = 1,D2_new
        DO i1 = 1,D1
            IF (lambda_1(i1)>Truncation) THEN
                A_update(i1,i2,im) = S1_tmp(i1,im,i2)*SQRT(lambda_2_update(i2))/SQRT(lambda_1(i1))
                B_update(i2,i1,im) = S2_tmp(i1,im,i2)*SQRT(lambda_2_update(i2))/SQRT(lambda_1(i1))
            END IF
        END DO
    END DO
END DO

END SUBROUTINE TwoSiteUpdate
```

Above two subroutines are the time consuming part of the program. Without these two subroutines, the program is fine and the memory does not increase. With these two, the memory do increase when I use the parallel version.

Comment: Could you post a minimum compilable program that shows this behavior? Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank Alexander. I have post two relevant subroutines above, without which, the program is fine. But these two subroutines are important and cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether you used compound type with allocatable items in loops. You may also use OpenMP parallel directives and the -openmp compile option to manual control where to be paralleled, rather than the auto-parallel, as follows

```
$omp parallel do
do i = 1, n
...
$ ifort -openmp foo.f90
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have checked that I use the allocatable arrays correctly.